# Visual Studio stop tracing into strlen.asm

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, strlen

How can I prevent Visual Studio from tracing into strlen() and other such functions?

I have a source line like:

```
i = my_function(x, strlen(x));
```

When I step into this line of source, I don't want to step into strlen(), but only my_function().  Is there a way to remove these as I encounter them?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow... by "tracing" you me stepping through in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the line in the debugger and choose to step directly into my_function, or if the call has multiple argument function calls, you can step into one of your choosing from the right-click menu. This doesn't let you skip those automatically, but it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean stepping through the code in the debugger within Visual Studio. You should be able to just press <kbd>F10</kbd> to step over code when you're on that line. If you press <kbd>F11</kbd>, that'll step into the code which means you'll travel down into the code for `strlen()`.